# Initializing floating value of UNION in C

Tags: c

I have below union,

```
typedef union
{
  struct
  {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float Backup;
  } pt;
  float Max[4];
} Var3D;
```

When I try to initialize above union like `Var3D= { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };`

It shows build error like

> ```
> suggest braces around initialization of subobject
> [-Werror,-Wmissing-braces]
> Var3D= {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
> ```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens when your follow the advice "suggest braces around initialization of subobject" and put `{}` around `{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}`?

Comment: It would help if you gave an actual code sample.    `3DVar` is not a valid identifier, so your `typedef` would not compile.    In any event, assuming your ACTUAL code (as distinct from the code you have posted) has a valid `typedef` name other than `3DVar`,  try doing as the error message suggests:  `YourType some_variable = {{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}};`.   Note there are two sets of `{}`.     In future, read up on how to ask a question in a way that is more likely to get useful responses, in particular provision of a [mcve].

Comment: Adding braces like below resolves, 
{{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}}

but i don't understand the 
{{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}}; --> Resolve this.

But {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0} is already initialization. I don't understand this clearly.

Braces are already present and this is of union type. So when we initialize larger size member.

Comment: A pair of `{}` is used when initialising an aggregate (i.e. something initialised as a set of values).   A `struct` is an aggregate, an array is an aggregate, and a union is also an aggregate.    Your type is a union containing a struct and an array (albeit in the same memory location), so it is an aggregate of aggregates.   Hence the need for nested pairs of `{}`.

Comment: Note that you can't use the type name `3Dvar` — identifiers cannot start with digits.  You also don't show a valid variable definition.  Maybe you need to use a type name such as `Var3D` and then the variable definition would be `Var3D var3d = { .pt = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 } };` using a designated initializer, or you can drop the `.pt =` and leave the doubled braces to initialize correctly.  Technically, that undesignated notation initializes the first element of the union, which is `pt`.  You could designate the alternative with `.Max =` in place of `.pt =`.  The net result is the same here.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan and Peter for your explanation.

Comment: This union isn't such a good idea really. It's undefined behaviour to assign one member and then access another,

Comment: @n.m.: In C, unlike C++, it is not undefined to access a member other than the last one stored. Per the C standard, the bytes are reinterpreted as the new type. There may be implementation-defined effects.

Answer (score 0):

So make an answer:

As Peter mentioned you need two pair of braces: one for the union and one for the array included in the union.
So this initialization should work:

```
Var3D= {{ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }};
```